# Looping issue while attempting to add a growing bar to my game

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

The bar should slowly fill up after 5 seconds, though the user should not be able to click it within those five seconds. How would I go about simultaneously achieving these two things?

```
amount = 1
barlength = 102
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            (x, y) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if x < 200 and x > 100 and y < 200 and y > 100 and amount > 0:
                currenttime = time.clock()
                print (currenttime)
                while time.clock() < currenttime + 5:
                    #untilfull = timez/barlength
                    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, (0, 0, 0), pygame.Rect(20, 20, barlength, 40))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progress bar inside a button in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163736/progress-bar-inside-a-button-in-pygame)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything inside your game loop that prevents the loop from running over a period of time. You'll have to move your drawing code to outside of your event loop. Otherwise this will cause your game to appear frozen to the operating system. You'll need to set the value of `currenttime` either outside of the loop or as the result of an event (such as pressing a specific key). Instead of using a `while` loop to check the time, just use a normal `if` statement. Because the game loop (the outer `while` loop) is constantly running, the `if` statement will continually run.

As for making the bar grow in length, multiply the bar length by the amount of time that's progressed since `currenttime` and divide by 5.

Also, I'd recommend using `time.time()` instead for assigning `currenttime`, which is just the current unix timestamp in seconds.

Something like...

`pygame.Rect(20, 20, int(barlength * (time.time() - currenttime) / 5), 40)`

Comment: Thanks! I made it so it  will grow if you click inside the desired box, but it only increments partially per click... How would I make it so I click, and then it grows, rather than I have to spawn click the box. I've tried using loops to do this, but these loops would prevent the game from running.I will put my code over the code in my initial post if you want to read through it. My problem only occurs on lines 70-79. Thanks for all the help!